# Навешивание основных стилей на глобальные теги body, header, section, footer

Tags: html, css, рефакторинг

Доброй ночи, стараюсь привести код в максимально аккуратный вид, но боюсь переборщить. Приветствуется ли практика глобального навешивания стилей

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 1024px;
    font-family:'Engravers-Gothic';
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #999;
}
```

и тому подобное, или лучше разбивать на более мелкие части?

Также буду рад услышать Ваши советы/пожелания.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут пересекаются две штуки:

1. Общее задание (сброс) стилей для всего документа - задать всем элементам font-family, font-size по умолчанию, определить максимальную ширину и т.п.
2. Здание общих стилей элементов

По первому пункту стоит сначала применить какой-нибудь [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) для нормализации стилей во всех браузерах, потом на `<html>` повесить необходимые общие стили - те самые font-size, font-family, -webkit-font-adjust, etc. При этом отмечу, что вешать ширину на `<body>` - практика не очень: `<body>` относится к обязательным тегам и не выполняет роль визуального контейнера в документе.

По поводу второго: скорее всего, вы захотите задать стили по умолчанию всяким `h1`-`h6`, `.pull-right`, однако с `<header>`/`<footer>` эта штука вряд ли пройдет просто потому, что `<header>` для всего документа и `<header>` внутри `<article>` будут выполнять абсолютно разные функции. Вам не следует объединять то, что не объединено логически.

Третий пункт, которого не было в перечислении - попробуйте препроцессор (LESS, SASS или Stylus). Во-первых, многие проблемы с CSS уйдут сами собой (например, опечатки в сложных селекторах), во-вторых, код будет куда нагляднее, в-третьих, вы сможете разбить блоки по файлам и подключать их в общий файл поочередно, что позволит разгрести традиционные авгиевы конюшни в CSS. А заодно и многие вещи начнут получаться сами собой: в `base/01-default.sass` устанавливаем значения по умолчанию, в `chunks/01-article.sass` переопределяем то, что нужно для статей.